# Packet Sniffing through proxy PC via router

Tags: proxy, http, packet-capture

i have a linksys wireless N router.  I want to setup a proxy on my Windows 7 PC along with a packet sniffer, and setup my devices to use the proxy on the Windows 7 PC.

So far, I've tried Squid, but it's too cumbersome and the command line is not my strong suit.  I am just looking for info on a quick to set up proxy which can just analyze all outgoing and incoming connections.

I've installed Wireshark but it looks like a mess of options as well.

Are there any two easy to use GUI enabled proxy servers and packet sniffers out there for Windows?

I tried installing Squid on my Mac but it keeps complaining about file permissions even though I already set them to Read & Write.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want your pc to just be a HTTP proxy or to do full routing?

Comment: Pardon my noobness, but all I want to do is have all traffic pass through the PC, no other routing.  If I'm playing PS3, I want my PS3 traffic to pass through the PC before it goes to the Internet.  I can manually set the proxy on the PS3 to be 192.168.1.104, which is what the IP of my Windows 7 PC is.

Answer (score 1):

Squid is only a HTTP proxy.  Are you sure you want the traffic to *pass* through the PC, or do you just want to monitor all traffic on the network?  Passing through the PC is a lot harder with only 1 interface card.  Unfortunately, a lot of these tools are somewhat complex to use, because, well, it is a complex thing you're trying to do.  Wireshark will definitely be able to monitor all traffic on the network.  Proxying, unfortunately, for all sorts of traffic (not just HTTP) is a lot harder.

Answer (score 1):

In case you only want to monitor traffic, another option would be to invest in a network hub (search eBay) or a switch with mirror port. I've used a [Netgear GS105E](http://netgear.se/business/products/switches/prosafe-plus-switches/gs105e.aspx) with great success in the past, not too expensive either.

Then you can plug in your Windows machine to the mirroring port and capture the traffic there. That way you don't affect what your measuring (I'm sure I'll get comments about this :p) which you might do with a proxy, and there's no configuration needed on the client side.